# Запрет выполнения функции во время выполнения ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть функция, выполняюшая ajax запрос. После выполнения выставляются новые параметры для следующего ajax запроса.

**Вопрос**: как не дать выполниться функции ещё раз, пока совершается ajax запрос? Вся проблема в том, что если быстро запускать событие с запросом, то новые параметры не успевают установиться.

Вот код:

```
var next_cursor = '';
var count = 0;
$.getJSON(
    "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=<?php echo $_COOKIE['instaphp'];?>&cursor=" 
        + next_cursor 
        + "&callback=?",     
    function(data){
        $.each(
            data.data,
            function(i,item){
                $("<li></li>").html('<s>' + item.username + '</s>').appendTo("#list_fol");
            }
        );
        next_cursor = data.pagination.next_cursor;
    }
);

$(document).scroll(
    function(){
        if( $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300 <= $(document).scrollTop()) {
            $.getJSON(
                "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=<?php echo $_COOKIE['instaphp'];?>&cursor=" 
                    + next_cursor 
                    + "&callback=?",     
                function(data){
                    $.each(
                        data.data,
                        function(i,item){
                            $("<li></li>").html('<s>' + item.username + '</s>').appendTo("#list_fol");
                            count++;
                        }
                    );
                    next_cursor = data.pagination.next_cursor;
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var next_cursor = '',
    count = 0,
    updating = false,
    pending = false,
    $document = $(document),
    $window = $(window);

var update = function() {
  if (updating) {
    pending = true;
  } else {
    updating = true;

    var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=<?php echo $_COOKIE['instaphp'];?>&cursor=" + next_cursor + "&callback=?"

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
        $("<li></li>").html('<s>' + item.username + '</s>').appendTo("#list_fol");
      });

      next_cursor = data.pagination.next_cursor;
      updating = false;

      if (pending) {
        pending = false;
        update();
      }
    });
  }
};

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.height() - $window.height() - 300 <= $document.scrollTop()) {
    update();
  }
});

update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Устанавливайте переменную статуса. Запрос выполняется - она true, закончил выполняться - false. Проверяйте перед выполнением ajax запроса, чтобы статус был false.

Comment: щя попробуем

Comment: @sergiks так норм?

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    is_in_process = 'true';
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    is_in_process = 'false;
    });

Comment: Как вариант, только без кавычек вокруг `true` и `false`. И перед очередным `$.getJSON()` убедитесь, что `is_in_progress == false`, иначе не выполняйте его пока.

Ответ @inso гораздо более продуман, чем мой поверхностный совет.